# What are the default values for synclient parameters?

Tags: lubuntu, xorg, touchpad

I'm running Lubuntu 16.10. In trying to troubleshoot my finicky trackpad, I've changed the values of my `synclient` parameters in a wild and uncontrolled way. How can I restore the parameters to their default values? If it can only be done manually, one by one, does X.Org maintain documentation somewhere with a list of default parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you switch user to the guest session it should have the default values and run the command `synclient -l >/tmp/touchpadsettings` then you can switch back to your user and run `synclient -l >~/brokentouchpad` Then you can run `diff /tmp/touchpadsettings ~/brokentouchpad` to see the changes and for all of the values you changed you can run synclient  name of setting = value in /tmp/touchpadsettings. For example in the diff command I could totally turn the touchpad off making it not respond with synclient touchpadoff=1 But in the diff I get on one line synclient touchpadoff=0 on one then synclient touchpadoff=1 on the lower line so run synclient touchpadoff=0 to fix it.